# How to distinguish between effects that adjust a battle form's special statistics and those that don't?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, polymorph

[Polymorph](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) states that:

> If you take on a battle form with a polymorph spell, **the special statistics can be adjusted only by circumstance bonuses, status bonuses, and penalties.**

However, I'm having a trouble distinguishing between effects that adjust a battle form's special statistics and those that don't. What's tripping me up is that a lot of effects *could* be statistics, but I don't know if granting such effects counts as adjusting the form's special statistics. **Especially if the form has a special statistic that would be supplanted in practice by the effect.**

For example, consider [spider climb](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=299), [darkvision](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=60), [sacred defense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1183), or [ring of fire resistance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=455), which grant effects that are special statistics for some or all battle forms.

- If the form has a worse climbing speed, low-light vision, some temporary Hit Points left, or a worse resistance to fire, are my examples adjustments to these special statistics?
- If the form doesn't have a climbing speed, low-light vision, any temporary Hit Points left, or resistance to fire, are my examples still adjustments to special statistic 'groups'? I.e adjustments to speeds, to senses, to temporary Hit Points, or to resistances respectively.

This question is not about effects that mess with a battle form's attack statistics.

Answer (score 2):

## Anything should be allowed that does not change an existing *numerical* value (unless it is a circumstance or status bonus)

(I doubt even the designers could could convincingly explain what they meant, as the rules are unclear, but I will try to work through it using common sense. An errata or clarification would be very useful)

Based on the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adjust), "adjust" means:

> to **change** something slightly, especially to make it more correct, effective, or suitable

So my reasoning here is that something *new* is acceptable, *altering values* is not.

### Temporary Hit Points

By a strict reading of the rules, the tHP granted by the spell would never change, as it is a "statistic", and damage taken is not a "penalty", so it cannot "adjust" the values.

Which obviously makes no sense. So you can give tHP to the polymorphed PC.

### Resistance

The question is, if an [Owlbear](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=328) has a *fire resistance 0*, or *no resistance*.

1. If it had 0, a Ring of Fire Resistance would "adjust" it, which is not permissible
2. If it had no resistance at all, this is a new thing, and allowed

Surprisingly (at least to me) there are no strong arguments to either one, but the 2nd one feels more natural. So Ring of Fire Resistance should be allowed for forms without any resistance of the same type.
However, a Major Ring of Fire Resistance grants 15 against fire, and someone polymorphed into a Red Dragon through [Dragon Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=88) has already 10. In this form the fire resistance stays 10. But the ring should work while in Green Dragon form.
Which again makes no sense, but these seem to be the rules.

An effect that increases your resistance as a *circumstance or status bonus* would work, but I am not aware of any such thing.

### Climb Speed

Just like with **Resistance**, it works on forms *without* a current Climb Speed, but not on ones with.

So Spider Climb does not work on an Ape from Animal Form, but Longstrider does, as it is a status bonus.

### Darkvision

It is not adjusting the "level of vision", as it is not a thing, it is providing a new ability, so it should work.

Comment: @brandon, you are right, I will change my phrasing

Answer (score 2):

### Statistics vs Abilities

The *Core Rulebook's* [introduction chapter](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1) describes statistics very broadly:

> **Level** is one of the most important statistics of the game
>
> Proficiency gives you a bonus that’s added when determining the following modifiers and statistics: **AC, attack rolls, Perception, saving throws, skills, and the effectiveness of spells.**
>
> While the roll of the die is critical, the statistic you add to the roll (**called a modifier**) often makes the difference between success and failure.

And abilities are similarly described:

> ...a PC’s class defines the majority of their aptitudes and abilities, **like a wizard’s command of powerful arcane spells or a druid’s power to transform into a fearsome beast**!
>
> In addition to these key choices, player characters also have a number of **feats**— individual abilities selected during character creation and as the character increases in level. Every feat has a type to denote where its explanation can be found (for example, elf feats can be found in the elf ancestry) and its theme (wizard feats, for example, grant abilities that deal with spells).
>
> If your character’s ancestry provides them with special abilities, write them in the appropriate spaces, such as **darkvision** in the Senses section on the first page and **innate spells** on the fourth page.

Assuming that the "effectiveness of spells" refers to spell DC and modifiers to spell damage, this suggests that statistics are the numerical values used for determining outcomes and that abilities cover what a character can do outside of the ordinary.

### Battle Forms

This means that the numerical values given by the polymorph spells can only be adjusted according to the exception above, by circumstance modifiers. The AC given by the spell isn't adjusted by things like your character's armor or Dexterity, but you would still be affected by the circumstance penalty from being [flat-footed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=16).

Abilities like darkvision aren't limited by this rule, so the spell *darkvision* would work normally regardless of what the polymorph spell granted for vision.

### Adding New Statistics

The limitation for polymorph spells could be interpreted to cover statistics that aren't given by the spell, but given that it calls out being "adjusted only by circumstance bonuses, status bonuses, and penalties" it seems more likely to just cover what kinds of modifiers can be applied to the statistics granted by the spell.

So while a character's [Fleet](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=784) ability wouldn't increase a battle form's land speed by 5 feet because it isn't a circumstance bonus, they could cast *spider climb* to gain a climb speed equal to their land speed, regardless of whether the form granted a climb speed of its own.

Similarly a *ring of fire resistance* isn't modifying any existing resistance to fire so it would apply regardless of what the battle form granted. Only the highest [resistance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=346) would apply to any given instance of damage.

> If you gain temporary Hit Points when you already have some, choose whether to keep the amount you already have and their corresponding duration or to gain the new temporary Hit Points and their duration.

[Temporary Hit Points](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=385) have their own exception for what happens when you get another source of them that seems to allow the character to choose which source to keep, so Sacred Defense would work as well:

Answer (score 1):

Battle form spells say, in part, 'You gain the following statistics and abilities...' This implies the list includes stats and abilities, and anything not one must be the other. From a natural language reading, I would expect statistics to be the numeric items and modifiers, and the abilities to be everything else.

Comment: How would you respond then to Ruse's two specific questions at the end of the post then? "Yes" and "No"? "Yes" and "Yes"?